# how to make an object minimise again when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small form that is expanded when a user visits my webpage and then minimises after a few seconds. Then when the button is clicked it expands again. I have been trying to add code to allow it to minimise when the button is clicked again but i keep breaking it. Im a beginner with jquery, can anyone help?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ambersabre/vkfos3yn/

html:

```
<div id="fixed-form">

    <div style="width: 100%; height: 43px">
        <div id="btnclick" class="contactbtn" />
        <div style="padding-top: 12px; font-size: 14px; padding-left: 26px; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase">send us an email</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content" id="testdiv">

    <div style="margin: 0  auto; width: 340px; height: 130px; padding-top: 5px">

    <div style="padding-top: 10px">
        <div style="float: left; width: 165px; height: 37px">
            <input type="text" class="float-input" name="contactName" id="contactName" value="" class="txt requiredField" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS:" />
        </div>

        <button name="float-submit" type="submit" class="float-submit" style="margin-top: 8px; margin-left: 10px" value="float-submit" />Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#fixed-form {
    position: fixed; z-index: 1;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 400px;
}
.content {
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 400px; height: 180px;
    font-family:Lato; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; border: 2px solid grey;
    font-size:14.5px; position: relative; z-index: 1; border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.contactbtn {
    width: 192px; position: relative; z-index: 1; float: right;
    height: 43px; background: grey;
}
.float-input {
    width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none; background: #46A2A2;background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#testdiv").slideToggle(1500);
        }, 5000)
        $('#btnclick').click(function () {
            $('#testdiv').show();
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("").slideToggle(1500);
            }, 5000)
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: There is a tide up button in fiddle :)

Comment: basically if u use call back function then your code is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

My example includes sliding up and down, I'm not sure if this acceptable, but it does work.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $(function() {
    setTimeout(function() { $("#testdiv").slideToggle(1500); }, 5000)
    $('#btnclick').click(function() {
        $("#testdiv").slideToggle(1500);
    })
})
```

})

Answer (score 3):

As you are using `.slideToggle()` use it again instead of `.show()`

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $("#testdiv").slideToggle(1500);
}, 5000)

$('#btnclick').click(function () {
    $('#testdiv').slideToggle();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/Lpv27bxs/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/65bhj6th/5/

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
       $(function() {
       setTimeout(function() { $("#testdiv").slideToggle(1500); }, 5000)
       $('#btnclick').click(function() {
       $('#testdiv').slideToggle(1500);
       setTimeout(function() { $("").slideToggle(1500); }, 5000)
       })
    })
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
  setTimeout(function() { 
    $("#testdiv").slideToggle(1500); }, 5000)
  $('#btnclick').click(function() {
    $('#testdiv').slideToggle(1500);
  })
 })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this jquery code **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/vkfos3yn/5/)**

```
$('#btnclick').click(function() {
$('#testdiv').slideToggle( "slow" );
});
```